# beautifulsoup not returning complete html of the page in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have taken help to extract data from the package BeautifulSoup, but unfortunately, it does not give me the output of the complete HTM file.

```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import requests

   url = 'https://www.digikala.com/search/category-mobile-phone/?page=1'
   response = requests.get(url)
   print(response.text)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"lxml")
   m= soup.find_all("h2", {'class':'ellipsis-2 text-body2-strong 
    color-700'})
   print(m)
```

Comment: Does the page use javascript to dynamically create content?  If so, then that's the problem, because the `requests` module does not understand javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page is loading data from an API. You can see this by inspecting Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools, reloading the page.

The following code will return a json with all items from page 1:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://api.digikala.com/v1/categories/mobile-phone/search/?page=1'
response = requests.get(url).json()
print(response)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand how you got the URL

Comment: I understand, thank you
But your suggested solution did not help me.
My problem is that I can't get the same html code that is in Inspect, the elements tab and do a search.

Comment: Page is dynamic, data is loaded by JS script. You won't be able to use request to do what you say 'get the same html code that is in Inspect, the elements tab and do a search.' with requests, you would need another solution, like selenium, to do it.